# Not updating indexes in maven eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I have problem updating my maven central repository in eclipse..
I have tried everything I could find on internet..

- Checking/unchecking options
- Deleting files/folders related to m2
- Updating maven project and removing all error from it
- Rebuild indexes
- etc etc

I have even completely deleted my eclipse, installed everything from scratch.. and even created new project[not imported old one]

I am still not able to solve this issue..

Please help me with this issue